# Displayport monitor to HDMI video card

Tags: video, graphics-card, hdmi, displayport

I recently purchased the following:

Computer - XPS 8900 w/ NVIDIA(R) GeForce(R) GT 730 2GB DDR3

Monitor  - Dell 22-inch Monitor - E2216H

My issue is that the monitor has VGA and Displayport and the card has HDMI, VGA and I think DVI.

Currently I have it plugged into the displayport on the motherboard so I'm using the integrated video, but would like to use the video card.

I'm been searching the web and I'm confused on which cable or converter I should buy.   I want to make sure I get the best video possible without spending a lot of money.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you could use the VGA port without experiencing any image quality loss. Besides the input lag of the VGA is lower than HDMI and Displayport and the fact that you need to buy an adapter is more likely to affect the image quality than than fact that you are using VGA which normally should not have any impact on your image.

Comment: That is the best possible answer.  Thank you.